# Required angular directive not found

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to understand the execution of link function in angular directives. However, I am stuck in a very simple setup. Following is the html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="demoApp">
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="DemoController" class="container">
      <directiveone directivetwo ></directiveone>
    </div>
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

"demoApp" is defined in app.js as follows:

```
angular.module('demoApp', [])
.controller("DemoController", function(){

})
.directive("directiveone", function(){
    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs){
        console.log("directiveone link called");
    };
    return {
        link : linker
    }
})
.directive("directivetwo", function(){
    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs){
        console.log("directivetwo link called");
    };
    return {
        require: "directiveone",
        link : linker
    };
});
```

When I run this code, I get the error:

`Controller 'directiveone', required by directive 'directivetwo', can't be found!`

I am unable to figure out the error here. Documentation suggests it might be a typo, but it is not apparent to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directives default to attribute-only. Your `directiveone` directive isn't being picked up - you need to specify `restrict: 'E'` in its definition, or apply it as an attribute (`<div directiveone directivetwo>...`)

Comment: Yes, the documentation says it defaults to E and A. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-restrict- but then I realised the documentation is for v1.3.0 and I am using 1.2.26.